# Disable Output Cache for a Special Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a big e-Commerce ASP.NET MVC project. I use output cache for cache system but I need to turn off output cache for a special link. I know I can do it with separate action but I don't want to use another action. I need to turn off it in same action.

Thanks for your solutions.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom  = "none")]
public ActionResult CheckIsCustomPage(string sefLink)
{
   //for example i need here like this
   //if (sefLink=="blablabla.html"){
   // turnoff output cache
   // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a custom Implementation of OutputCache attribute

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method,
        AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class OutputCacheVary : OutputCacheAttribute
{
    public OutputCacheVary()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string paramText = filterContext.ActionParameters["sefLink"].ToString();

        if (paramText == "blablabla.html")
        {
            NoStore = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Duration = 3600;
            VaryByCustom = "none";
        }
    }
}
```